# Data initialization and data members change in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I cannot figure out how you declare a "Data" type and how you can initialize a variable with that type. I'd also like to know how can I change the values of certain members of that variable. For exaple :

```
data Memory a = A 
  { cameFrom :: Maybe Direction
  , lastVal :: val
  , visited :: [Direction]
  }
```

Direction is a Data type that contains N,S,E,W
val is a Type int

```
init :: Int -> a
init n = ((Nothing) n []) gives me the following error:


The function `Nothing' is applied to two arguments,
but its type `Maybe a0' has none
In the expression: ((Nothing) n [])
In an equation for `init': init n = ((Nothing) n [])
```

how can I fix this ?

UPDATE: That did it, thank you very much, but now i have another issue

```
move :: val -> [Direction] -> Memory -> Direction
move s cs m | s < m.lastVal = m.cameFrom
            | ...
```

this gives me the following error:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `a0 -> c0'
    Expected type: val
      Actual type: a0 -> c0
    In the second argument of `(<)', namely `m . lastVal'
    In the expression: s < m . lastVal
```

UPDATE 2: Again, that helped me a lot, thank you very much

Also, I have another question (sorry for being such a bother)

How do I adress only an element of a type
For example if I have

```
Type Cell = (Int, Int)
Type Direction = (Cell, Int)
```

how do I proceed if I want to compare a Cell variable with the Cell element of a Direction variable?

Comment: Do you mean `lastVal :: a`, to match up with `data Memory a`?

Comment: These are pretty basic questions; have you read the section on records and other data types in whatever tutorial or book you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the update.  The syntax

```
m.lastVal
```

and

```
m.cameFrom
```

is not what you want.  Instead

```
move s cs m | s < lastVal m = cameFrom m
```

accessors are just functions, so used in prefix form.  The `.` in Haskell is used for namespace resolution (which is not path dependent) and for function composition

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

Answer (score 1):

To initialise:

```
init :: Int -> Memory Int
init n = A {cameFrom = Nothing, lastVal = n, visited = []}
```

To change values: strictly speaking you don't change values, you return another different value, like this:

```
toGetBackTo :: Direction -> Memory a -> Memory a
toGetBackTo dir memory = memory {cameFrom = Just dir, visited = dir : visited memory}
```